# Use index to label results in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql, pg

I have generated a list of files that different users have uploaded.

```
2 Pen writing 83746__braffe2__pen-writing.wav audio/wav 1057836 2013-11-17 03:43:29 UTC

3 Pen writing 83746__braffe2__pen-writing.wav audio/wav 1057836 2013-11-17 03:46:26 UTC

4 Pen writing 83746__braffe2__pen-writing.wav audio/wav 1057836 2013-11-17 03:51:41 UTC

5 Pen writing 83746__braffe2__pen-writing.wav audio/wav 1057836 2013-11-17 03:55:48 UTC
```

Here is the code snippet that generated the list:

```
<% @sounds.each do |sound| %>
  <%= sound.id %>
  <%= sound.sound_name %>
  <%= sound.rating %>
  <%= sound.user_id %>
  <%= sound.sound_file_file_name %>
  <%= sound.sound_file_content_type %>
  <%= sound.sound_file_file_size %>
  <%= sound.sound_file_updated_at %> 
  <%= button_to "Download", download_path(sound.id), :method => :get %>

<% end %>
```

However, I want to show which user uploaded which file.  A user can have many sounds, and sounds belong to a user.  I am using postgresql as my database.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sounds
end

class Sound < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

From my schema:

```
  create_table "sounds", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.string   "location"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "sound_file_file_name"
    t.string   "sound_file_content_type"
    t.integer  "sound_file_file_size"
    t.datetime "sound_file_updated_at"
    t.string   "sound_name"
  end

  add_index "sounds", ["user_id"], name: "index_sounds_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

From what I can tell, the user_id field is not getting filled for some reason.  From my controller:

```
def new
    @sound = Sound.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def create
   @sound = Sound.create( sound_params )
   redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @sound.id, :user_id => current_user
end

private

# Use strong_parameters for attribute whitelisting
# Be sure to update your create() and update() controller methods.

def sound_params
  params.require(:sound).permit(
    :sound_file,
    :sound_name,
    :description,
    :location,
    :user_id => current_user)
end
```

Here is the form that the user uses to create a sound:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @sound], :url => "/users/:user_id/sounds", :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :sound_name, placeholder: "Sound name" %>
  <%= form.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description" %>
  <%= form.text_field :location, placeholder: "Location" %>

  <%= form.file_field :sound_file %>
 <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?  Or am I just completely misunderstanding how an index works in Rails?

**UPDATE 1**

I made the following changes in my controller:

```
  def create
    @sound = Sound.create( sound_params ).merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
    redirect_to :action => "show"
  end


  def sound_params
    params.require(:sound).permit(
      :sound_file,
      :sound_name,
      :description,
      :location,
      :user_id)
    end
```

I ended up with this error message:

```
undefined method `merge' for #<Sound:0x007fa6a4a61ec0>
```

Looks like this is the problem line:

```
@sound = Sound.create( sound_params ).merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

My guess is that Rails is mad because the Sound object does not come with the merge function.  I am kind of surprised what a pain this is.  I just want to be able to select sounds that belong to a user.  I guess I don't really understand how these relations are implemented with rails.

I did notice this in one of my migrations:

```
class CreateSounds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sounds do |t|
    t.string :sound_name
    t.string :description
    t.integer :rating
    t.string :location
    t.references :user, index: true

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

However, when I look at my database, I don't see any reference to user in the columns.

```
HearHere_development=# SELECT * from sounds;
id |       description       | rating |       location       | user_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         |      sound_file_file_name       | sound_file_content_type | sound_file_file_size |   sound_file_updated_at    |   sound_name
```

Comment: is current_user in def create nil?

Answer (score 2):

so you're trying to merge user_id (which is an integer) with a user (which is an object). you need to make sure you have the types matching. one way to rewrite:

```
def create
  @sound = Sound.create( sound_params ).merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
  redirect_to :action => "show"
end

def sound_params
  params.require(:sound).permit(
  :sound_file,
  :sound_name,
  :description,
  :location,
  :user_id)
end
```

you could also add a hidden field in your form, for :user_id, :value => current_user.id

Comment: I got an error message: undefined method `merge' for #<Sound:0x007fa6a4a61ec0>.  I'll update my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass the user id in using a hidden field:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @sound], :url => "/users/:user_id/sounds", :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :sound_name, placeholder: "Sound name" %>
  <%= form.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description" %>
  <%= form.text_field :location, placeholder: "Location" %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
  <%= form.file_field :sound_file %>
  <%= form.submit %>
```

In the controller:

```
  def create
    @sound = Sound.create( sound_params )
    redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @sound.id, :user_id => current_user
  end


 def sound_params
    params.require(:sound).permit(
      :sound_file,
      :sound_name,
      :description,
      :location,
      :user_id)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another way.  Since I set up the initial relationship in the models, I can just do this.

```
  def create
    @sound = current_user.sounds.create( sound_params )
    redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @sound.id, :user_id => current_user
  end

  private

 def sound_params
    params.require(:sound).permit(
     :sound_file,
     :sound_name,
     :description,
     :location
    )
 end
```